# In General Relativity can electric field-induced tension in a Bose-Einstein Condensate reduce the energy needed to create an anti-gravitational field?

Tags: general-relativity, electric-fields, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, dipole, bose-einstein-condensate

This is my theory showing how an electric field can create an anti-gravitational field. It is based on Einstein's General Relativity (GR), and the ability of an electric field to induce tension in atomic dipoles.

In the GR field equation

[image]

tensor T  represents this  matrix:

[image]

The terms in green  T11, T22, and T33   are the Euclidean space x, y, and z  components of the pressure vector. Positive pressure is the outward-directed force normal to a unit surface area

P = F/A

Negative pressure, tension, is  tensile stress, and can be thought of as the inward-directed force normal to a  unit surface area:

σ  = -F/A

The GR field equation shows that negative pressure tension specified in the Energy-Stress-Momentum tensor changes spacetime curvature to create a repulsive anti-gravitational field.

An electric field can induce well-known polarized electric dipoles in a material, pulling the electron in an atom away from the positively charged nucleus, elongating, and stretching the electron cloud toward the positive side of the field. But I recognized this concept, that physics and chemistry textbooks never mention:

The attraction between the electron and proton acts with an equal force in the opposite direction, This is tension. In fact, a vibrating spring under tension is used to model the electron cloud that comprises the atomic bond between two atoms; and this model is used to determine the infrared frequencies/wavelengths of a vibrating atomic bond.

In this diagram of an electric field-induced atomic dipole,  in the lower right corner  I inserted  the tensile stress  vectors and an explanation of how the electric field induces this  tension in the atomic dipole:

[image]

So an electric field applied to a material creates tension in the dipoles that it induces.

The GR field equation shows that tension changes spacetime curvature to create a repulsive anti-gravitational field. Therefore the dipole tension induced by an electric field would be expected to create an anti-gravitational field.

Now, this is a point that confuses most people:

**This electron stretching tension induced in atoms by an electric field**

is not  the same as

**the tension component of the Electromagnetic Stress–Energy tensor that applies to free space**.

The  tension component of the Electromagnetic Stress-Energy tensor that applies to free space is intrinsic  tension  characteristic of the electromagnetic field unto itself. But the tension we are talking about here is  stretched electron tension in  the atoms of a material induced by an electric field. These are 2 different tensions.

When considering the Electromagnetic Stress-Energy tensor, the negative  gravity field  caused by intrinsic electric field tension,  and the  positive gravity field caused by intrinsic electric field energy density cancel: resulting in no net anti-gravitational field. But the additional negative gravitational field, from the stretched electron tension in the atoms,  still remains.

This negative gravitational field  is opposed by the positive gravitational field caused by the mass-energy density of the atoms. But if the electric field strength is great enough,  the magnitude of the negative gravitational field caused by atom electron tension, will exceed the  magnitude of the positive gravitational field caused by the mass-energy density: resulting in a net anti-gravitational field.

**^^^^^^^+++++++^^^^^^^+++++++^^^^^^^+++++++^^^^^^^+++++++**

**Reduction of the Energy Requirement**

The following derivation  based on  GR basic  principles proves that within a Bose-Einstein Condensate, the tension needed  to create an anti-gravitational field is reduced by many orders of magnitude:

Superconductors and superfluids contain Bose-Einstein Condensates (BECs) because a BEC is required to induce superconductivity and superfluidity. Two decades ago Lene Haue at Harvard University discovered that a BEC slows down the speed of light by many orders of magnitude. This is the pivotal concept that eliminates the issue of the impractically large amount of energy/tension required to create an anti-gravitational field.

Starting  from  1st principles,  Einstein's requirement to measure time: Place two mirrors parallel to each other separated by a distance d. Bounce light back and forth between the mirrors. Count N = number of times the  light returns to 1  mirror during the measurement period. Then

**DistanceLightTraveled** = 2dN

Einstein assumed that the two mirrors are in a vacuum. Knowing the speed of light  in a vacuum is c = 3x10^(8) m/s, the   time interval t  between 2 events is

t = **DistanceLightTraveled** / **SpeedOfLightBetweenMirrors**

= 2dN / c

This is the method Einstein requires to determine  the time interval t  between 2 events.

Minkowski incorporated this  into the spacetime 4-vector

[**DistanceLightTraveled** x y z ] = [**ct** x y z]

where **ct** represents **DistanceLightTraveled** measured  as described above, and  (x,y,z) are the  Euclidian space 3D  coordinates of the mirrors   that measure **DistanceLightTraveled**.

Einstein and Minkowski assumed that the 2 mirrors are in a vacuum, where light travels at 3 x 10^(8) m/s .

But what if all the locations under consideration are underwater, for example? The speed of light through  water is less than in a vacuum: it travels at 0.75c  in water. That means  light will bounce back and forth between the mirrors more slowly in water than in a vacuum. And it  will make fewer round trips N between the mirrors in water than a vacuum.

Nwater < Nvacuum

So in water

**DistanceLightTraveledwater**  = 2dNwater

and in a vacuum

**DistanceLightTraveledvacuum** = 2dNvacuum

Since Nwater < Nvacuum

**DistanceLightTraveledwater**  < **DistanceLightTraveledvacuum**

In  the terms  of the GR field equations  that contain the speed of light :

"**c**" is taken  from the 1st component of the generic spacetime 4-vector

[**DistanceLightTraveled** x y z ] = [**ct** x y z]

and subbed into **SpeedOfLightBetweenMirrors**  to determine the time interval t:

t = **DistanceLightTraveled** / **SpeedOfLightBetweenMirrors**

t =  **DistanceLightTraveled** / **c**

However,  when the mirrors are not in a vacuum, but for example in a medium such as water where the speed of light, **Vm**, is 0.75c,  when    the  GR field equations  inherit  spacetime 4-vector

[**ct** x y z]

and **c** is subbed  from this spacetime 4-vetor  into  **SpeedOfLightBetweenMirrors** , the time interval  will  be

t = **DistanceLightTraveled** / **SpeedOfLightBetweenMirrors**

= **DistanceLightTraveled** / **c**

which is wrong

- - because the **SpeedOfLightBetweenMirrors**   in water is not **c**

it is  **0.75c**

That means when the medium is not a vacuum,  "**c**" can no longer be subbed from the generic spacetime vector

[**ct** x y z]

into **SpeedOfLightBetweenMirrors,** to get the  time interval because that will give the incorrect time t.

To get the correct time t,  the original generic spacetime 4-vector must be changed from

[**DistanceLightTraveled** x y z ] = [**ct** x y z]

to

[**DistanceLightTraveled** x y z ] = [**Vmt** x y z]

where **Vm** is the speed of light in the medium where the mirrors are located.

Then "**Vm**" can subbed from  the 1st component of the modified  generic spacetime vector

[**Vmt** x y z]

into **SpeedOfLightBetweenMirrors**

and that will give the correct time interval:

t = **DistanceLightTraveled** / **SpeedOfLightBetweenMirrors**

= **DistanceLightTraveled** / **Vm**

where **Vm** is the speed of light in the medium where the mirrors are located at    coordinates (x,y,z).

This  generalized spacetime 4-vector

[**Vmt** x y z]

is used to derive the Energy-Stress-Momentum tensor **T** in the GR field equation

[image]

[image]

The Energy-Stress-Momentum tensor **T** is the outer product of the **4-momentum vector** and the **number flux 4-vector**. And these  vectors are derived from  the above modified spacetime vector

[**Vmt** x y z].

- Here is the derivation of the **4-momuntum vector**:

[**Vmt** x y z] / t = [**Vm** x/t y/t z/t]

= [**Vm** Ux Uy Uz] This is the 4-velocity vector where Ux, Uy, Uz are the 3 spatial velocity vector components of a particle with mass m.

m [**Vm** Ux Uy Uz]= [m**Vm** mUx mUy mUz]

This is the **4-Mometum vector** of a particle with mass m.

- Here is the derivation of the **number flux 4-vector**:

Let n  be the number of particles with mass m in a unit volume xyz. The  4-velocity vector multiplied by n is

n[**Vm** Ux Uy Uz] = [n**Vm** nUx nUy nUz]

This is the **number flux 4-vector**.

The **Energy-Stress-Momentum tensor, T,** is the outer product of the **4-mometum vector** of a particle with mass m

[m**Vm** mUx mUy mUz]

and the **number flux 4-vector**

[n**Vm** nUx nUy nUz]

The resulting Energy-Stress-Momentum tensor on RHS of the  GR field equation is the rank 2 tensor T with 16 matrix components. T00, the component in the upper left of the matrix, is obtained by multiplying component 0 of the 4-momentum vector

m**Vm**

by component 0 of the number flux 4-vector

n**Vm**

T00 = (m**Vm**)(n**Vm**) = nm**Vm**^(2)

And, just like  with the **Energy-Stress-Momentum tensor**,  components  of the **Einstein tensor**  are also  derived from the spacetime 4-vector modified from

[**ct** x y z]

to

[**Vmt** x y z].

The GR field equation **coupling constant** is derived from the  Energy-Stress-Momentum tensor    and   Einstein tensor, that are derived from  spacetime 4-vector

[**Vmt** x y z] ...

so that leads to a coupling constant with **Vm** in the denominator:

[image]

Since the speed of light  **Vm** in a Bose-Einstein Condensate  medium is many orders of magnitude less than the speed of light in a vacuum,  the GR field equation with the  modified coupling constant  shows that the tension required to create an anti-gravitational field is many orders of magnitude less in a Bose-Einstein Condensate than in a vacuum.

This means it is theoretically possible to Engineer an anti-gravitational field if electric field dipole tension is induced within a Bose-Einstein Condensate.

^^^^^^^+++++++^^^^^^^+++++++^^^^^^^+++++++^^^^^^^+++++++

The generalized field equation shows that when the speed of light in the medium under consideration,   Vm,   goes to 0,  the magnitude of the induced  G field becomes becomes infinite

[image]

This  means when Lene Haue produced a  Bose-Einstein Condensate that reduced the speed of light to 0, it should have created an infinitely strong gravitational field that would have destroyed the Earth. Since this didn't happen -  it means the derivation appears to be incorrect.

But, what Lene Haue didn't consider is the fact that an attractive gravitational field caused by the  mass-enegy density  of the BEC causes time dilation. GPS satellites  correct for this gravitational time  dilation -- where time passes faster in the GPS satellite hundreds of miles above the Earth than on the ground.

As Lene Hau's  BEC (with a minuscule mass on the order or a few thousand or million electrons) became more concentrated, reducing the speed of light more and more -  resulting in an increasingly strong gravitational field,  gravitational time dilation would gradually increase as well. She  obviously  didn't correct for gravitational time dilation when she determined the speed of light in the BEC:

The slower passage of time in the BEC creates the illusion that the light in the BEC is moving in slow motion; so the detector would see the light moving slower than it really was moving - because the detector saw   the combined effect of

*{slowdown of light caused by BEC impedance}*

+

*{slowdown of light caused by  gravitational time dilation}*

This means when the  detector measured  light moving at  of 0 m/s, the light could have been moving much faster than than that. But  within the limits of accuracy of the detector, the gravitational time dilation component created the illusion that the speed of light decreased to 0.

This  shows that an argument {that the BEC allegedly slowed the speed of light to 0 but didn't destroy the Earth} cannot be used to negate the validity of the generalized GR field equation.

I'd be happy  to hear your critique.

E: Construct4321@proton.me

Comment: Please stop editing this question as long as your edits are not addressing the close reason. [Post now locked for a week since you did not, in fact, stop]

Answer (score 3):

There are three major problems with your theory in the context of generally accepted physics.

First, while it is true that an electric field does contain negative terms in its stress-energy tensor, it also has positive terms; in particular, it has a positive energy density.  Specifically, the [stress-energy tensor associated with a uniform electric field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor) in the $x$-direction is
$$
T^{00} = T^{yy} = T^{zz} = \frac{1}{2} \epsilon_0 E^2 \qquad T^{xx} = -\frac{1}{2} \epsilon_0 E^2 
$$
(in units where $c = 1$.)  This means that the "repulsive" effects from the components of the stress-energy you're interested in are inherently not the only thing that is going on;  you also have to take into account the "attractive" components from the energy density of the fields.  If you actually put an electromagnetic field density into the weak-field limit of Einstein's equations, you will find that the equations reduce to
$$
\Box h_{\mu \nu} = - \frac{16 \pi G}{c^4} T_{\mu \nu}
$$
and so the $h_{00}$ component (which is the most important one for non-relativistic particle motion) is only affected by the positive energy density;  the effects of the negative pressure are cancelled out by the other positive components of the stress-energy tensor.

Second, you are postulating that Einstein's equation is modified in a medium by the replacement of $c \to v$, where $v$ is the speed of electromagnetic waves in this medium.  This is not the accepted interpretation of Einstein's equations;  the $c$ in that equation is the same regardless of the medium in which light is traveling.  If your interpretation were correct, then well-known experiments in which [the speed of light is taken to zero in a medium](https://www.discovermagazine.com/the-sciences/freezing-light-in-its-tracks) would have led to an infinite mass/energy density and formed a black hole in the lab.  Seeing as *[checks notes]* the Earth was not destroyed in 2013, this does not seem to be the case.

Finally, I should note that any effects from the electric field in a medium will be much, much smaller than the effects of the mass density of the medium itself.  So while a strong electric field in a medium might change the gravitational field created by that medium on the margins, it will generally not entirely reverse these effects.